# how to create a user in postgres to connect to nodejs?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

It is my first time using postgres and I am trying to use it with node. I installed postgres in Ubuntu and created the user admin

```
sudo -i -u postgres
createuser --interactive
```

in my node code I tried to connect to postgres:

```
let { Client } = require('pg');
conn = new Client({host:'localhost', port:5432, database:'web-viewer', user: 'admin'});
conn.connect();
```

but I get this error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password authentication failed for user "admin"

my pg_hba.conf was

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

then I changed to

```
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

to try to add a password to my admin user, but when I "createuser --interactive" again, I get this error

> createuser: error: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

how can I prepare the postgreSQL to connect to node?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't parse the password in your `new Client` definition:

> in my node code I tried to connect to postgres:
>
> ```
> let { Client } = require('pg');
> conn = new Client({host:'localhost', port:5432, database:'web-viewer', user: 'admin'});
> conn.connect();
> ```

change it like the following, using the information you saved during the user creation:

```
let { Client } = require('pg');
conn = new Client({
    host:'localhost', 
    port:5432, 
    database:'web-viewer', 
    user: 'admin',
    password: 'yourpassword'  
});
conn.connect();
```

[Follow the doc](https://node-postgres.com/api/client#:%7E:text=example%20to%20create%20a%20client%20with%20specific%20connection%20information%3A).

btw, to avoid using sensible information (your password), consider creating [environment variables](https://nodejs.dev/learn/how-to-read-environment-variables-from-nodejs).

---

I know the post is 8 months old, but you never know.